# Error de respuesta en Dropzone

Tags: php, laravel, json, xmlhttprequest

Buen dia, estoy desarrollando un formulario en el que tengo que subir imágenes, y al querer devolver el valor de mi imagen me devuelve este error. Desconozco por que esta pasando esto, previamente ya había usado Dropzone en otro proyecto con Laravel.
De lo que estoy seguro es que el problema proviene del controlador y no del app.js de Dropzone ni del Form del HTML.

Anexo error en el navegador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi controlador:

```
    public function store(Request $request){
    $imagen = $request->file('file');

    return response()->json(['imagen' => $imagen->extension()]);
}
```

Me sería de mucha ayuda si alguien me dijera en lo que me estoy equivocando o estoy errando algo en mi código, muchas gracias.

Comment: Creo que el título de la pregunta está una palabra errónea

Comment: Buen día, muchas gracias por la observación, ya lo corregí.

Answer (score 0):

el error que yo tenia es que los módulos de JavaScript dentro del archivo app.js de la carpeta de resources de mi proyecto Laravel, sino un archivo aparte de este, la solución fue agregarlos al archivo de vite.config.js

Un saludo si alguien presenta o presentaba el mismo error que yo, gracias.